# Authenticate user using condition in java

Tags: spring-boot

> I want to perform below Operation  using conditions.
> 1.If user is going to authenticate in that case below operation cannot be happen.

```
.addHeader("Bearer", brandwiseBearerToken)
```

2. 

> if user is authenticated then below above things perform
>
> for your reference I post my code.

```
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).post(body)
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").addHeader("Bearer", brandwiseBearerToken)
                        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a if-else condition should do what you want.

```
Request request;
Builder builder = new Request.Builder().url(url).post(body)
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
if(//check for authentification){
    request = builder.addHeader("Bearer", brandwiseBearerToken).build();
}else{
    request = builder.build();
}
```

This will add the header if the user is authenticated and will build the request without the Header, if they are not.